# Grouping two tables EF core aggregation

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to create a route that gets the stats about topics, so I tried using join and groupBy to achieve it, I want the result display categoryId, title, body and total topics per category but I got this error with my implementation.

> .GroupBy(x => x.title)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

Please does anyone know how to solve this?

```
public class Topic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TItle { get; set; }
    public string body { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet("stats")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> getTopicStats()
       {
          var stats = _context.Topics.Join(
                _context.Categories,
                topic => topic.CategoryId,
                cat => cat.Id,
                (topic, cat) => new
                {
                    catId = topic.CategoryId,
                    desc = cat.Description,
                    title = cat.Title
                }).GroupBy(x => x.title);
            await stats.ToListAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(stats);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't join in LINQ-to-Entities.  Just follow your Navigation Properties.

> want the result display categoryId, title, body and total topics per category

So with proper Navigation properties,

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Topic> Topics {get; set;} = new HashSet<Topic>();
}
```

this is something like:

```
from c in db.Categories
select new 
{ 
  c.CategoryId,
  CategoryTitle = c.Title,
  CategoryDescription = c.Description,
  TopicCount = c.Topics.Count() 
};
```

Comment: With this way I can't access c.Topics, there is no information about Topic in category table

Comment: But there should be.  See updated answer.